# XSLT error after setting up dd4t with java

Tags: 2013, dd4t, java

We have setup DD4T with java as per URL https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/31_Quickstart

We have ported the content porter package from https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/tree/master/java

After setting up tomcat, we are getting below error while requesting index.jsp from tomcat.

```
    2015-12-10 15:04:17,563 ERROR XSLTransformer - Unable to load XSL : Could not compile stylesheet
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:832) ~[xalan.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.SmartTransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(SmartTransformerFactoryImpl.java:319) ~[xalan.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.util.XSLTransformer.getTransformer(XSLTransformer.java:119) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.util.XSLTransformer.transformSourceFromFilesource(XSLTransformer.java:66) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveXhtmlField(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:150) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveMap(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:124) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveComponent(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:113) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolvePage(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:104) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.doFilter(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:84) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.BaseFactory.doFilter(BaseFactory.java:152) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.BaseFactory.doFilters(BaseFactory.java:128) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.GenericPageFactory.findGenericPageByUrl(GenericPageFactory.java:250) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.GenericPageFactory.findPageByUrl(GenericPageFactory.java:209) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.springmvc.controller.DynamicPageController.handleRequestInternal(DynamicPageController.java:124) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
2015-12-10 15:04:17,564 ERROR XSLTransformer - Error transformer from template with name /resolveXhtmlWithLinks.xslt.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.dd4t.core.util.XSLTransformer.getTransformer(XSLTransformer.java:130) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.util.XSLTransformer.transformSourceFromFilesource(XSLTransformer.java:66) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveXhtmlField(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:150) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveMap(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:124) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolveComponent(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:113) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.resolvePage(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:104) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.filters.impl.RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.doFilter(RichTextWithLinksResolverFilter.java:84) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.BaseFactory.doFilter(BaseFactory.java:152) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.BaseFactory.doFilters(BaseFactory.java:128) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.GenericPageFactory.findGenericPageByUrl(GenericPageFactory.java:250) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.GenericPageFactory.findPageByUrl(GenericPageFactory.java:209) [dd4t-core-1.31.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.springmvc.controller.DynamicPageController.handleRequestInternal(DynamicPageController.java:124) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

The item has been published to the broker too.

Comment: Can you verify whether resolveXhtmlWithLinks.xslt is in your web app somewhere?